# D3.js version3 scale.ordinal() not reading in my data the way I would like

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am building a dot plot histogram with d3.js v3 and I am trying to color code my data based off one of the variables I read in from my csv file (it's city, which there's 10 of them). Problem is every dot is the same color when I run it in the browser.

Anyone know whats going on?

Heres a snapshot of my code:

```
var data = d3.csv('happy.csv', function(data) {

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d["index"] = d["index"];
    d["name"] = d["name"];
    d["city"] = d["city];
    ...
 })

var colorScheme = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .domain(data, (function(d) {
                    return d.city
                }))
                .range(["#FFADAF", "#FFC980", "#D9D9D9", "#9DACCB", "#95D1A5", 
                "#F586C6", "#BFDD81", "#F18489", "#80BCEC", "#FEFEA9"]);

...

var dots = groups.selectAll("circle")
.data(function(d) {
    return d3.range(1, +d.index + 1)
})
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("class", "dot")
.attr("r", 7.5)
.attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d)
})
.style("fill", function (d) { return colorScheme(d.city); } )

})
```

Comment: If you log city with `.attr("fill", function(d) { console.log(d.city); return colorScheme(d.city); })` it logs undefined right?

Comment: @AndrewReid Yes it does!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bind each item in your data array to `groups`, and then use that data to create a data array to bind to child circles:

```
return d.range(1, +d.index + 1);
```

The problem is d3.range is just producing an array of numbers for the specified range. There is no `city` property for this bound datum, which is just a number: there's no trace of the original datum bound to the parent `group` carried forward as part of the datum bound to the child. Consequently, each time you try to color the circles by `d.city` you are passing `undefined` to the scale, as this is the only value passed to the scale, all circles are all the same color.

Instead you could use `d3.range` and `array.map()` to bind an array of objects to the children that carry forward the city property:

```
return d3.range(1, +d.index + 1).map(function(c) {
  return {city: d.city, index: c}
})
```

Now we have the city property carried forward to the circles:

```js
var data = [
  {index: 5, city: "A"},
  {index: 4, city: "B"},
  {index: 6, city: "C"}
];

var colorScheme = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .domain(data, (function(d) {
                    return d.city
                }))
                .range(["#FFADAF", "#FFC980", "#D9D9D9", "#9DACCB", "#95D1A5", 
                "#F586C6", "#BFDD81", "#F18489", "#80BCEC", "#FEFEA9"]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

var groups = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",function(d,i) {
    return "translate("+[0,i*20]+")";
  })

var dots = groups.selectAll("circle")
.data(function(d) {
    return d3.range(1, +d.index + 1).map(function(c) {
      return {city: d.city, index: c}
    })
})
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("class", "dot")
.attr("r", 7.5)
.attr("cx", function(d,i) {
  return i*20+10;
})
.attr("cy", function(d,i) {
    return 60;
})
.style("fill", function (d) { return colorScheme(d.city); } )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, we could access the parent datum with `d3.select(this.parentNode).datum()` when coloring the circles:

```
.style("fill", function (d) { return    colorScheme(d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().city); } )
```

As follows:

```js
var data = [
  {index: 5, city: "A"},
  {index: 4, city: "B"},
  {index: 6, city: "C"}
];

var colorScheme = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .domain(data, (function(d) {
                    return d.city
                }))
                .range(["#FFADAF", "#FFC980", "#D9D9D9", "#9DACCB", "#95D1A5", 
                "#F586C6", "#BFDD81", "#F18489", "#80BCEC", "#FEFEA9"]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

var groups = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",function(d,i) {
    return "translate("+[0,i*20]+")";
  })

var dots = groups.selectAll("circle")
.data(function(d) {
    return d3.range(1, +d.index + 1)
})
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("class", "dot")
.attr("r", 7.5)
.attr("cx", function(d,i) {
  return i*20+10;
})
.attr("cy", function(d,i) {
    return 60;
})
.style("fill", function (d) { return colorScheme(d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().city); } )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Or, we could apply the fill at the level of the parent and skip applying a fill at all for the children:

```js
var data = [
  {index: 5, city: "A"},
  {index: 4, city: "B"},
  {index: 6, city: "C"}
];

var colorScheme = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .domain(data, (function(d) {
                    return d.city
                }))
                .range(["#FFADAF", "#FFC980", "#D9D9D9", "#9DACCB", "#95D1A5", 
                "#F586C6", "#BFDD81", "#F18489", "#80BCEC", "#FEFEA9"]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

var groups = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",function(d,i) {
    return "translate("+[0,i*20]+")";
  })
  .attr("fill", function(d) { return colorScheme(d.city); })

var dots = groups.selectAll("circle")
.data(function(d) {
    return d3.range(1, +d.index + 1)
})
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("class", "dot")
.attr("r", 7.5)
.attr("cx", function(d,i) {
  return i*20+10;
})
.attr("cy", function(d,i) {
    return 60;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```